# Strange coalesce result when second value is null

Tags: mysql

I have been chasing a problem for hours, which seems to come from my misunderstanding of the coalesce function in mySql.

Running the following:

```
SET @a=30;
SET @b=NULL;
SELECT COALESCE(@a, @b) c;
```

Will result in c being a blob, NOT 30. What is going on, isn't the coalesce operator supposed just to return @a and stop there? Feels like I'm missing something really basic (this is using a 5.7 Docker image)

The specs seem pretty clear though....?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

**Edit 08/14**

To dig further on nbk's answer and comment (on the fact that I am using here user defined variable), my real case is closer to this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
set @a=NULL, set @b=NULL;
...
SELECT autoIncrementId INTO @a FROM aTable WHERE something;
...
INSERT INTO aTable (SELECT something WHERE @a IS NULL);
SET @b=LAST_INSERT_ID();
...
SELECT COALESCE(@a, @b) c;
COMMIT;
```

I keep on using @a and @b this way, in doing different conditional insert and updates. I know there are different ways of doing conditional inserts, but this one doesn't mess up autoincrements, which I like.

But independently of this, I always end up with @a or @b being set to an auto incremented index's value. Shouldn't their type be known to mySql as being an INT?

Comment: Works well for me. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rnoG84NzJYUb1HD8ZcYC6E/0 ... Must be something else.

Comment: Is this the whole code, or is it part of a larger query?

Comment: @Barmar this was part of a much larger query, where I'm reconciling two 'LAST_INSERT_ID()' results towards the end, to run some cleanup queries. But it really boils down to what I provided as an example here, and which doesn't work on my server (I'm running this dummy example through mySql workbench, and it gives me the same type of behaviour a my full app, running a nodejs mysql client)

Comment: There are contexts where MySQL automatically converts types, such as subqueries in a `UNION` that return different datatypes for the same column.

Comment: nbk's answer points this way too. I learned something today :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is for mysql a binary string values (BINARY/VARBINARY type), that is why it shows BLOB, you have to CAST it like

```
SET @a=30;
SET @b=NULL;
SELECT  CAST(COALESCE(@a, @b) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
```

Result:

```
CAST(COALESCE(@a, @b) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
'30'
```

Comment: This is quite strange. The specs state that `The return type of COALESCE() is the aggregated type of the argument types. ` I would expect this to mean that the return would be a numerical value... really strange! Thanks.

Comment: you use user defined variables and not columns with a defined datattyoe

Comment: OK thanks for the details. I have expanded my question, purely to try to understand what is going on, not so much to fix/modify a mySql syntax. If you have further comments, I am all ears :-)

Comment: i see, i like stored procedures with its DECLARe possibilities